# How to test update method with unit test

Tags: unit-testing, delphi

I have a method to update database data, is there a way to test if the method is working using unit test?
Would like to test if the changes were successful.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking this would be an integration test as unit test must not interact with other external resources like databases, web services or the file system.

However from a technical perspective there is no limitation to use the unit test library or framework of your liking to do this. It would follow the same AAA pattern as unit tests:

- **A**rrange data in your test database
- **A**ct by calling your update method
- **A**ssert that the data was changed as expected by querying from the test database